# jQuery script or plugin that can do template/layout selection?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Question - I'm not jQuery expert by any means. So I can't code from scratch. I'm looking to create a "template selector" similar to the following image:

http://www.socialbungy.com/saas_mock/page2.jpg

I was thinking of some sort of image gallery script, but I'm not sure it would work correctly.

Please note, I just want the template selector, not the rest of the site mock up.

Comment: "template selector"?  can't it just be an image selector and depending on what image the use clicks, use that? (I guess I don't get what you want to process).  Also, it's generally advised that you try to do this yourself and then, when you get stuck, post on here asking about a specific concept. (e.g. How do you implement options in this jQuery plugin template?  How do I center this block? etc.)

Comment: @joseph Sorry, seems everything I post on here people say I'm doing something wrong. lol I'm a newbie. I thought this would be the best place to ask. Essentially, it is a concept question though - just don't have code to back it up. Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any image gallery would work fine--you only need to select an image representing the template, and move forward from there once you've identified the template (like with an ID, name, or whatever unique identifier you have).

Comment: Thanks for your help Dave. This is what I thought. Quick question, get's a quick answer. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

You could try this one: http://www.tn3gallery.com

It looks similar to the template selector you mentioned.